# No longer able to access tty

Tags: 16.04, gnome, tty

I recently switched to Ubuntu gnome, before this i was always able to access tty via `ctrl+alt+f1,f2...f6`. But know if i try one of these combination everything stuck and i need to force shutdown the system with the power button

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say it. 16.04

Comment: Do you use proprietary nvidia garphics driver? And gmome-screensaver? Can you confirm [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1811402)?

Comment: @jarno I'm no longer using that laptop nor ubuntu 16.04, but when I was using it, I'm pretty sure i was using gnome-screensaver and proprietary nvidia drivers.

Comment: I have the bug in 18.04.